# Photoelectric Effect Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

Say in a photoelectric experiment, we find a stopping potential of 1.85V for $\lambda=3000\overset{\circ}{A}$ and of 0.82V for $\lambda = 4000 \overset{\circ}{A}$.

1. How can I get the Planck's constant from the above information?
2. Determine the work function of the sodium in electron-volts.
3. Determine the threshold wavelength for sodium.

For 1, I converted the wavelengths to meters, and got $3\times10^{-7}m$ and $4\times10^{-7}m$. I know these formulas: $\lambda\times c = v$, $E=hv$. How do I get the energy, is there a formula that I miss?

For 2, I have no idea about how to get the work function, my professor didn't teach anything about it. Are there any good references? (And for 3 as well).

Thanks for any hint and help!

Comment: $c=f\lambda$ where $c$ is the speed of light, $f$ is frequency and $\lambda$ is wavelength. And Kinetic energy of ejected electron is $KE=E_0-\phi=h(f-f_0)$, so work function it calculated using: $\phi=hf-KE$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $hv = hv_{0} + K.E.$ where $v_{0}$ is the threshold frequency. In this problem we have been given $ \lambda $ instead of $v$. So use the known relation $v= \frac{c}{\lambda}$ to get $v$.

Moreover we don't have the K.E. directly. Instead we have been given a stopping potential, that is the potential required to stop the electron. So to get K.E., use the relation 
$ \text{K.E.} = eV$ where $e$ is electronic charge.

Since the threshold frequency is constant for a metal, we will get two equations form the given data, and by solving them , we can get the value of $h$ and plugging it in any of the equations, we get $v_{0}$. Rest all is easy.

Note: Work function is the $hv_{0}$ term in the first equation. It is the minimum energy required for an electron to free from the metal's surface.

Sorry for disorganized writing!

References: http://www.ncert.nic.in/NCERTS/textbook/textbook.htm?kech1=2-7 
Open up chapter two in this and scroll down to get information on photoelectric effect. Its written nicely.

Comment: So actually work function is just a value, not a function, right?